# Mouse curser disappearing on login

Tags: gnome, login

For some reason the mouse didn't appear on login but appeared fine enough when I did log in. There were also several other problems like text being cut in half or something. So I decided to do the good old trick of turning it off and then back on (Although I had to do a hard reset since it got stuck).

After turning back on the usual weird stuff happened like it'd flicker between a black screen and the GNOME splash screen and then eventually right back to login.
Well doing seemed to have fixed all the problems except for the mouse has still disappeared on login.

I tried updating and using the command `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false` but neither had worked.

TL;DR Mouse won't appear on login, tried fixes, didn't work.

---

Edit: I've installed Trusty Tahr over 13.10 and the problem seems to have solved itself